# How can I update a data in a TList<T>?

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

I have this record (structure):

```
type
    THexData = record            
            Address : Cardinal;
            DataLen : Cardinal;
            Data    : string;    
    end;
```

And I've declared this list:

```
HexDataList: TList<THexData>;
```

I've filled the list with some data. Now I'd like scan ListHexData and sometimes update a element of a record inside *HexDataList*.

Is it possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var
  Item: THexData;
... 
for i := 0 to HexDataList.Count-1 do begin
  Item := HexDataList[i];
  //update Item
  HexDataList[i] := Item;
end;
```

The bind is that you would like to modify `HexDataList[i]` in place, but you can't. When I'm working with a `TList<T>` that holds records I actually sub-class `TList<T>` and replace the `Items` property with one that returns a pointer to the item, rather than a copy of the item. That allows for inplace modification.

**EDIT**

Looking at my code again I realise that I don't actually sub-class `TList<T>` because it the class is too private to extract pointers to the underlying data. That's probably a good decision.  What I actually do is implement my own generic list class and that allows me the freedom to return pointers to records if needed.

Comment: Ok @David. This code works. But is it possible to do that with _for in_ statement?

Comment: @O Engenheiro You can't do it with `for in` using a vanilla TList<T>. You'd have to sub-class the way I have done.

Comment: +1 One of the reasons why I almost always tend to use classes instead of records (the fact that no default constructor and destructor is possible being the other big reason)

Comment: @Smasher Good points. As a counter-point, my app is numerical (it's an FE code) and so I love records for operator overloading. I also appreciate having value types that go on the stack which is important for me.