# Writing a generic TList of records

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

I am trying to write a generic TList that contains records of a specific type. Starting from David's answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212783/generic-tlist-of-records-with-a-sub-list), I have written this class:

```
Type
  TMERecordList<T> = Class(TList<T>)
  Public Type
    P = ^T;
  Private
    Function GetItem(Index: Integer): P;
  Public
    Procedure Assign(Source: TMERecordList<T>); Virtual;
    Function First: P; Inline;
    Function Last: P; Inline;
    Property Items[Index: Integer]: P Read GetItem;
  End;

Procedure TMERecordList<T>.Assign(Source: TMERecordList<T>);
Var
  SrcItem: T;
Begin
  Clear;
  For SrcItem In Source Do
    Add(SrcItem);
End;

Function TMERecordList<T>.First: P;
Begin
  Result := Items[0];
End;

Function TMERecordList<T>.GetItem(Index: Integer): P;
Begin
  If (Index < 0) Or (Index >= Count) Then
    Raise EArgumentOutOfRangeException.CreateRes(@SArgumentOutOfRange);
  Result := @List[Index];
End;

Function TMERecordList<T>.Last: P;
Begin
  Result := Items[Count - 1];
End;
```

Having methods that return a pointer to the record works well (not perfectly) as pointers to records can be used as if they were records in most use cases. Using a record with properties and setters, these test cases work as expected:

```
  TMETestRecord = Record
  Private
    FID:     Word;
    FText:   String;
    FValues: TIntegers;
    Procedure SetID(Const Value: Word);
    Procedure SetText(Const Value: String);
    Procedure SetValues(Const Value: TIntegers);
  Public
    Property ID: Word Read FID Write SetID;
    Property Text: String Read FText Write SetText;
    Property Values: TIntegers Read FValues Write SetValues;
  End;

  // TestSetItem1
  rl2[0] := rl1[0];

  // TestSetItem2
  r.ID     := 9;
  r.Text   := 'XXXX';
  r.Values := [9, 99, 999, 9999];
  rl1[0]   := r;

  // TestAssignEmpty (rl0 is empty... after assign so should rl2)
  rl2.Assign(rl0);

  // TestAssignDeepCopies (modifications after assign should not affect both records)
  rl2.Assign(rl1);
  r.ID     := 9;
  r.Text   := 'XXXX';
  r.Values := [9, 99, 999, 9999];
  rl1[0]   := r;
```

### Problem 1 - modifying a contained record

... this test case compiles and runs but does not work as desired:

```
  // TestSetItemFields
  rl1[0].ID     := 9;
  rl1[0].Text   := 'XXXX';
  rl1[0].Values := [9, 99, 999, 9999];
```

Modifications are applied to temporary copy of the record and not to the one stored in the list. I know this is a known and expected behaviour, as documented in other questions.

But... is there a way around it? I was thinking that maybe if the TMERecordList<>.Items property had a setter the compiler could maybe do what is actually desired. Could it? I know David has got a solution, as hinted at in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968217/how-can-i-update-a-data-in-a-tlistt)... but I can't seem to find it on my own.

This would really be nice to have, as it would allow me to have a way of using the list identical (or almost) to that of a TList of objects. Having the same interface means I could easily change from objects to records and viceversa, when the need arises.

### Problem 2 - interface ambiguity

Having the TList<> return a record pointer does pose some interface ambiguity problems. Some TList<> methods accept T parameters, and we know that being records, these are going to be passed by value. So what should these methods do? Should I rethink them? I'm talking specifically about these sets of methods:

- Remove and RemoveItem
- Extract and ExtractItem
- Contains IndexOf, IndexOfItem and LastIndexOf

There is some ambiguity as to how these should test contained items to see if they match the parameter record value. The list could very well contain identical records and this could become a source of bugs in user code.

I tried not deriving it from TList<>, so as not to have these methods, but it was a mess. I couldn't write a class similar to TList without also writing my own TListHelper. Unfortunately System.Generics.Collections's one has some needed fields that are private, like FCount, and cannot be used outside the unit.

Comment: Writing a simple generic container is not hard and doesn't require anything like Emba's messy list helper. Which is still buggy.

Comment: Modify `rl1.List[0]` instead of `rl1[0]`. And the fact you don't have a default property does indeed make that the code resorts to the inherited indxed property (which should actually not make a difference, AFAICT).

Comment: When using pointers to elements of a TList you must realise that these pointers are volatile. When the list grows and gets reallocated the pointers will become invalid. Using records in a list can work but then the allocation of the records need to be done explicit like objects and the TList should hold the pointers to the allocated records and not to the elements in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Your Items property is not marked as being default. Hence your erroneous code is picking up the base class default property. Add the `default` keyword to your Items property:

```
property Items[Index: Integer]: P read GetItem; default;
```

**Problem 2**

This is really a consequence of deriving from `TList<T>`. I would not recommend doing that. Encapsulate an instance of `TList<T>` and therefore define the interface explicitly rather than inheriting it. Or implement the list functionality directly in your code. After all, it's not much more than a wrapper around a dynamic array.

For what it is worth my classes don't use `TList<T>` at all which is a decision that I was very happy with when Emba broke the class in a recent release.

Comment: As for Problem 1... nice catch, but it does not work as my Items property does not provide a setter, so is read only. I'll implement one and retry. As for Problem 2... I didn't know the rtl implementation is buggy, but you are certainly right and I will probably write my own implementation as soon as I find some time. For now the important thing is to provide a stable *interface* so other developers can start using it. Thanks. You have been very helpful

Comment: Don't understand your comment about problem 1. Read-only properties can be default.

Comment: "Emba broke the class in a recent release. " huh ?

Comment: The latest use a so called `TListHelper`. This has shown some issues (out of memory, AVs, etc.) where the original `TList<T>` didn't. I think the `TListHelper` doesn't treat managed records (i.e. records with a managed content) properly, but I am still trying to find what goes wrong where exactly. At first glance, `TListHelper` is OK, but I am giving it a few glances more. <g>

Comment: @Rudy It was broken in XE8 in many different ways. Subsequent releases improved matters. Clearly the test suite that Emba use was deficient. I hope it has been improved, but I couldn't get anybody to talk to me about that.

Comment: @David: do you have something I could test? I am trying to debug and improve upon this, but lack proper data that show the errors. I think I can make them accept the debugged sources. Just contact me as velthuis at gmail dot com. I know there still are issues. `TList<T>` and descendants are used extensively, even in the RTL and the visual libraries, so they should work extremely well in all circumstances.

Comment: @David: But many of my tests *assigned* records to the default property, which worked just because, as you correctly noticed, it was referring to the TList<>.Items property and not to my own.

Comment: The class is designed for `Items` to be a read-only property returning the address of an internal item. If you want to be able to write `List[i] := SomeRec` then this design is not for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent versions `TList<T>` in `System.Generics.Collections` contains a `List` property that gives you direct access to the backing array of the list. You can use that to manipulate the records inside the list.

Comment: I would and do use that internally. It would be sufficient to have it Protected. As noted elsewhere List has more items than Count and no range checking. Exposing it as Public to users is IMHO dangerous.